# How to convert raw input number to a list of integers in python?

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have this code:

```
guess = list()

playerNumber = raw_input
('Please enter a four digit number for which all the digits are different.')
p = str(playerNumber)

guess = [int(p[0]),int(p[1]),int(p[2]),int(p[3])]
```

I am trying to convert the raw input of a four digit number given by the user into a list of individual integers. My code is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: BTW, `raw_input` returns a String only. No need to use `str` on `playerNumber` here.

Answer (score 4):

I would have simply done, without compromising readability. Python built-in map, applies the call back to each element of a sequence and or iterable. Here it calls `int` to convert each of the elements of the sequence to integers. Another thing to note is, a string is a iterable, can be iterated over the individual characters

```
playerNumber = raw_input('Please enter a four digit number for which all the digits are different.')

playerNumber = map(int, playerNumber)
```

Comment: Ahh, I see what OP is saying now.  Nice.

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, sometimes its hard to understand what OP intends in his question

Comment: @Abhijit: For some reason I am getting the error "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable" when I use map( ) or when I try to individually make each element an integer, like this:

    `p = raw_input
    ('Please enter a four digit number for which all the digits are different.')

    g = list(p)
    
    guess = [int(g[0]),int(g[1]),int(g[2]),int(g[3])]`

Answer (score 0):

A bit more independence can be provided to the user in terms of entering the list of integers in a comma(or any other delimiter) separated way -

```
    listOfIntRaw = raw_input("Enter the numbers separated by comma - ")
    listOfInt = list(map(int,listOfIntRaw.split(',')))
```